# how to set-up hadoop cluster multi-node on ubuntu?

Tags: hadoop2

I want to install a multi node hadoop cluster. I want to have name node on one machine, job tracker on another, data nodes on seperate machines. Do I need to install hadoop on each of these machines and run some specific agents to run the name mode on machine a, hdfs on machine b, job tracker on machine c and so on. How do I go about setting this up?

Comment: Hi, I think this question is more suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: I think this is one of the best tutorial for hadoop 2 installation: http://pingax.com/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu-cluster-setup/